# How to access the entries in every row and apply custom functions?

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset, spark-structured-streaming

My input was a kafka-stream with only one value which is comma-separated. It looks like this.

"id,country,timestamp"

I already splitted the dataset so that i have something like the following structured stream

```
Dataset<Row> words = df
            .selectExpr("CAST (value AS STRING)")
            .as(Encoders.STRING())
            .withColumn("id", split(col("value"), ",").getItem(0))
            .withColumn("country", split(col("value"), ",").getItem(1))
            .withColumn("timestamp", split(col("value"), ",").getItem(2));


+----+---------+----------+
|id  |country  |timestamp |
+----+---------+----------+
|2922|de       |1231231232|
|4195|de       |1231232424|
|6796|fr       |1232412323|
+----+---------+----------+
```

Now I have a dataset with 3 columns. Now i want to use the entries in each row in a custom function e.g.

```
Dataset<String> words.map(row -> {
    //do something with every entry of each row e.g.
            Person person = new Person(id, country, timestamp);
            String name = person.getName();
            return name;
    };
```

In the end i want to sink out again a comma-separated String.

Comment: Can you show what you input looks like and the final output expected? I think this can be done better using spark sql and udf

Comment: well also the input and the output will be a comma-separated stream

Answer (score 0):

Data frame has  a schema so you cant just call a map function on it without defining a new schema.
You can either cast to RDD and use a map , or use a DF map with encoder.
Another option is I think you can use spark SQL with user defined functions, you can read about it.
If your use case is really simple as you are showing, doing something like :

```
var nameRdd = words.rdd.map(x => {f(x)})
```

which seems like is all you need
if you still want a dataframe you can use something like:

```
val schema = StructType(Seq[StructField](StructField(dataType = StringType, name = s"name")))
val rddToDf = nameRdd.map(name => Row.apply(name))
val df = sparkSession.createDataFrame(rddToDf, schema)
```

P.S dataframe === dataset

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom function that is not available by composing functions in the existing spark API[1], then you can either drop down to the RDD level (as @Ilya suggested), or use a UDF[2].

Typically I'll try to use the spark API functions on a dataframe whenever possible, as they generally will be the best optimized.

If thats not possible I will construct a UDF:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, udf}
val squared = udf((s: Long) => s * s)
display(spark.range(1, 20).select(squared(col("id")) as "id_squared"))
```

In your case you need to pass multiple columns to your UDF, you can pass them in comma separated `squared(col("col_a"), col("col_b"))`.

Since you are writing your UDF in Scala it should be pretty efficient, but keep in mind if you use Python, in general there will be extra latency due to data movements between JVM and Python.

[1]https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#package
[2]https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-scala.html